# How can we tell the potential from the orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, potential

The orbit is $$r(θ) = a(1+\cos θ).$$ The orbit of the particle is in polar coordinates. How can we tell the potential $U(r)$ from this? $U(r)$ goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: You can't. There's an infinite number of different functional forms $U(r)$ that can produce that orbit.

Comment: I want general form only.

Comment: Well you can't have it. All you can find out from that orbit is the form of the potential (and its derivative) along the orbit itself. It can take *any* form outside of it...

Comment: You at least need time dependence, and even in that case you'll only be able to recover _tangent_ hypersurface to the potential _on the trajectory_.

Comment: Hmmm... a cardioid orbit? One possible potential is of the form $r^{-4}$, if I remember correctly, but that's subject to the mentioned unknowns and I hardly think it's unique. I don't know what the most general form of the potential would be.

Comment: @CuriousOne - can you see my messages?

Comment: @DIYser: Apologies... didn't have much time today. Still working on something... just throwing one in once in a while for relaxation. :-)

Comment: No problem.  I was just wondering what happened to you because I sent multiple message via the chat room that we've used to converse & I didn't get any response from you.  I was beginning to wonder if you accidentally/intentionally clicked the "ignore this user" option.  I'll try again later in the week to initiate a chat with you or perhaps next week if this week isn't good for you.

Comment: No, don't worry... you are not on ignore. I still owe you the finish of the mechanical design, right? :-)

Comment: Well, no, not really 'owe'---but if you'd be so kind that would be way cool/good of you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37273/discussion-between-curiousone-and-diyser).

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is the [Binet equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation). Instead of using $r(\theta)$ it is better to define $u(\theta)=1/r(\theta)$, so that the orbit reads
$$
u(\theta)=\frac{1}{a(1+\cos\theta)}
$$

With this, the central force is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
F&=-k u^2(u''+u)\\
&=\frac{-k}{a^3(1+\cos\theta)^2}\left(\frac{1}{(1+\cos\theta)}+\frac{\cos\theta}{(1 + \cos\theta)^2} +\frac{2\sin^2\theta}{(1 + \cos\theta)^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{-3k}{a^3(1+\cos\theta)^4}\\&=-3ak u^4
\end{aligned}
$$

This means that the force is fiven by
$$
F(r)=\frac{-3ak}{r^4}
$$

Finally, the potential energy is given by
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}=-F(r)
$$
i.e.,
$$
V(r)=-\frac{a k}{r^3}+V(\infty)
$$